# Wrap a sentence into 3 rows at an exact point in a sentence

Tags: html, css

I have the following sentence on a single row on my webpage:

### Electrical Engineer & Mechanical Engineer

At a certain @media (max-width) I want to wrap the text onto 3 rows like this (obviously it will be centred):

### Electrical Engineer
&
Mechanical Engineer

How can I do this with CSS?

```
<!-- HTML -->
<h1 class="main-page-image-text">Electrical Engineer & Mechanical Engineer</h1>

/* CSS */
@media (max-width:800px) {
  .main-page-image-text h1 {
    Somehow split sentence at "&"?
}
}
```

Comment: upload your code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `<span class="breakpoint"></span>` in places where you want to have break

Now add css for it:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Adjust to your needs */
@media (max-width: 2800px) {
  .breakpoint {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
Electrical Engineer <span class="breakpoint"></span>&<span class="breakpoint"></span> Mechanical Engineer
</div>
```

---

If you want to make it dynamically **AND** you know exact phrases to split:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.wrapper').each(function () {
    var newContent = $(this)
        .text()
        .replace('&', '<span class="breakpoint">&</span>');
    $(this).html(newContent);
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Adjust to your needs */
@media (max-width: 2800px) {
  .breakpoint {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
Electrical Engineer & Mechanical Engineer
</div>
```